# Can't get objects into database in my BootStrap.config

Tags: grails

I am grails noob and I am following this tutorial: http://www.bobbywarner.com/2012/01/05/jump-into-grails-2-0/

I do: 
class BootStrap {

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
    def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)

    def user1 = SecUser.findByUsername('bobby') ?: new SecUser(username: 'bobby', enabled: true,  password: 'password').save(failOnError: true)
    if (user1.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
        SecUserRole.create(user1, userRole, true)
    }

    def user2 = SecUser.findByUsername('tony') ?: new SecUser(username: 'tony', enabled: true,  password: 'password').save(failOnError: true)
    if (user2.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
        SecUserRole.create(user1, userRole, true)
    }

    if (user2.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
        SecUserRole.create(user1, adminRole, true)
    }

    assert SecUser.count() == 2;
...
```

But when I start up I get:

```
| Error 2013-08-31 22:29:14,027 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Assertion failed: 
assert SecUser.count() == 2
               |       |
               0       false
```

I check my database and there are no SecUsers in the SecUser table.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `flush: true` inside your `save()` calls. This will force the objects to persist to the DB immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @grantmc points out, adding `flush:true` will help. But there are other problems with the code.

One is that you should be checking for `!contains`, not `contains` - if the User/Role grant isn't there, grant it. But the approach used is inefficient - it returns all of the existing records and checks for a match. That can also fail when proxies are used unless you create good `equals` and `hashCode` methods (not the case here though). It's far better to check if that one row exists, and it's easy with GORM:

```
class BootStrap {

   def init = { servletContext ->
      def adminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?:
                      new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
      def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?:
                     new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)

      def user1 = SecUser.findByUsername('bobby') ?:
                  new SecUser(username: 'bobby', enabled: true,  password: 'password').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user1, userRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user1, userRole, true)
      }

      def user2 = SecUser.findByUsername('tony') ?:
                  new SecUser(username: 'tony', enabled: true,  password: 'password').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user2, userRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user2, userRole, true)
      }

      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user2, adminRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user1, adminRole, true)
      }

      assert SecUser.count() == 2
      assert SecUserRole.count() == 3
      assert Role.count() == 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but an opinion for you on how to reduce your code to a good extent by using [findOrSaveWhere](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveWhere.html) and [findOrSaveBy*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html).

```
class BootStrap {
   def init = { servletContext ->
      def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
      def userRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_USER')

      //findOrCreateBy would be lengthy here as well, so back to original code
      def user1 = SecUser.findByUsername('bobby') ?:
              new SecUser(username: 'bobby', enabled: true,  password:  'password').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user1, userRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user1, userRole, true)
      }

      //findOrCreateBy would be lengthy here as well, so back to original code
      def user2 = SecUser.findByUsername('tony') ?:
              new SecUser(username: 'tony', enabled: true,  password: 'password').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user2, userRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user2, userRole, true)
      }

      if (!SecUserRole.findBySecUserAndRole(user2, adminRole)) {
         SecUserRole.create(user1, adminRole, true)
      }

      assert SecUser.count() == 2
      assert SecUserRole.count() == 3
      assert Role.count() == 2
   }
}
```

Comment: This will work in general, but findOrSaveWhere is tricky. If there's already a user with that username, but enabled is false, you'll create a 2nd and get an unexpected unique constraint violation on username. And if you use bcrypt or another password hash approach that doesn't hash to the same value each time, you'll miss on the password comparison. So it's more idiomatic, but a bit too clever imo.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Correct I did not emphasize on the context of the code above. I thought findOrCreateBy would be flexible and useful in that case instead of *saveWhere but that would be lengthy as well. Updated my answer reverting to old code, thanks for pointing that out. BTW, All the Best for your Harvard sessions. Let them know how to "Stay Groovy!!" :)